# Why am I getting a type error for the second pice of code while the first on worked?

Tags: python, numpy, types

Code:

```py
import numpy as np
#generate some fake data
x = np.random.random(10)*10
y = np.random.random(10)*10

print(x)    #[4.98113477 3.14756425 2.44010373 0.22081256 9.09519374 1.29612129 3.65639393 7.72182208 1.05662368 2.33318726]
col = np.where(x<1,'k',np.where(y<5,'b','r'))
print(col)  #['r' 'r' 'r' 'k' 'b' 'b' 'r' 'b' 'r' 'b']

t = []
for i in range(1,10):
    t.append(i)
    
print(t)  #[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

cols = np.where(t % 2 == 0,'b','r')
print(cols)
```

Error:

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-58-350816096da9> in <module>
      6 print(t)
      7 
----> 8 cols = np.where(t % 2 == 0,'b','r')
      9 print(cols)

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'list' and 'int'
```

I am trying to generate color code, blue for even and red for odd numbers.
Why do I get the error here, while it worked in the first piece of code?

Comment: `t` is a list (not a numpy array), and lists do not support the `%` operator. As the error message says.

Comment: You need to make `t` a numpy array, just like `x` in the first piece of code.

Answer (score 0):

The "first time" in your code snippet, `x` and `y` are numpy arrays, created from the calls to `np.random.random`:

```
col = np.where(x<1,'k',np.where(y<5,'b','r'))
```

This is not the case with `t`. As some of the comments have indicated, `t` is a generic Python list. You cannot apply the mod operator to a Python list.

```
>>> [1, 2, 3, 4] % 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'list' and 'int'
```

You can, however, apply the mod operator to a numpy array as Barmar indicated:

```py
t = np.array([2,3,4,5])
t % 2 
# returns array([0, 1, 0, 1])

np.where(t % 2 == 0, 'a', 'b')
# returns array(['a', 'b', 'a', 'b'], dtype='<U1')
```